# How to edit and move a file from one directory to another in one line in Linux?

Tags: linux, sed, mv

Happy new year.
I have a question.
I want to modify and move a file in `/etc/ansible` directory to my home directory in one shot.

With `sed` command i removed the `#` and empty lines. Now I want to move `ansible.cfg` to my home directory in the same command.

`~$ sudo sed -i.date +%F '/^\s*#/d;/^$/d' /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Comment: If you want to do this more than once, I would write a function for it.

Comment: one liners are highly overvalued  (IHM0). what about `sed -i .... file && mv file /path/to/new/location` ? And, you understand there is no way to do what you ask for literally? You will always have to save to your original file, copy to new location and delete old file?  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a file descriptor redirection?

`~$ sudo sed -i.date +%F '/^\s*#/d;/^$/d' /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg > /path/to/destination`

This won't remove or change the original file, however.

Comment: Using `-i` with a redirect is not ideal.  You should do only one.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Oh really? I was not aware of that, could you explain why?

Comment: `sed -i ...` is not going to generate any data on stdout.  If you redirect, then /path/to/destination is going to be an empty file and /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg is going to be written to.

Comment: Yes I agree with WilliamPursell. Can we use a `-`. How please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like that.

```
sudo sed -i.$(date +%F) '/^\s*#/d;/^$/d;w filename-in-your-home' /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```